# Unable to get lat and long using GPS provider

Tags: android, gps

ReminderLogic service class invokes GPSTracker Service class. isGPSEnabled is true. GPS was on in the device and was clearly under sky view. Still the lat and long is 0.0.

```
location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

and

```
location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

gives location as null.

Could someone please help me.

//ReminderLogic Service Class

```
            GPSTracker gps;
        double CurrLatitude, CurrLongitude;
        Location CurrentLoc;
        gps = new GPSTracker(HomePageActivity.this); 
if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                CurrLatitude = gps.getLatitude();
                CurrLongitude = gps.getLongitude();

                Toast.makeText(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        "canGetLocation is True. CurrLatitude and CurrLongitude is "
                                + CurrLatitude + CurrLongitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
```

//GPS Tracker Service class

```
          if (isGPSEnabled) {

                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I will explain your that why your code is not working.

You are using GPS to get the location which takes some time to get your location and on getting the location fires `onLocationChanged` Listener.

However, in your code you are asking GPS to get your location using

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

and then expecting it to give you location in a second. You need a `LocationListener` to listen to the location when GPS tracks you. This may take upto 20 minutes and depends on whether the GPS has a direct access to a satellite eg. if your device is inside a building, GPS will take several minutes to track you but if you in open the GPS will track you fast.

To use `LocationListener` just add `implements LocationListener` in your class declaration. Then in onLocationChanged() use the following to get your location.

```
@Override
     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null)
    {
       Log.d("Location Found", location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    } 
}
```

`locationManager.removeUpdates(this);` stops android from sending you locations endlessly and is important.

Also you can the `LocationListener` Class internally by using

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
              Log.d("Location Found", location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

        }
    }
```

But you must update the `requestLocationUpdates()` like this

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

**Update:-**

You are checking if your `locationManager` is not null after `requestLocationUpdates()` which won't be null since you initialized it. Then you are using

```
location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

to get the last Known Location which will only be present if you have earlier used any app to get a location. eg. if you use Google Maps app to get your location, then after Google Maps detect your position, you open your own app then you will get **LastKnownLocation**. This is due to the fact that android has your position from the past.

If you never got any location previously, then you won't get any result from it. Besides, this is the wrong way of coding. You should do like this

```
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
}
else{
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}
```

This way, if you have a previous location you can use it, if not, then you get a new one.

Comment: You mean to say I need to wait 20 minutes to get the location? But I have seen in sample apps it is workling.

Comment: I said that it might take upto 20 minutes. It depends where you are. GPS may lock you in 2 sec or 20 but it all depends on your location.

Comment: Can you please give me some time? I will test this and tell you. I am using Galaxy S3

Comment: Ofcourse, take you time. But remember when you are using **this** in `requestLocationUpdates()` then make sure that your activity extend `LocationListener` or you can use it internally as I mention in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
if (locationManager != null) {
    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    if (location != null) {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.